# Spring Boot init.d not Not running (process not found)

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to follow the instructions from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install), where trying to run the Spring Boot app as init.d service but could not successfully.

I created the fully executable jar (myapp.jar) as mentioned and also created the symlink to */etc/init.d/myapp* When I run the *java -jar myapp.jar* I could see the application start up successfully.

But when I try to use

`service myapp status` it says  `Not running (process  not found)`

`service myapp start` it says `Failed to start`

the documentation says "*Assuming that you have a Spring Boot application installed in /var/myapp*" I don't understand this point quite well. I copied the executable jar (via Jenkins) to /var/myapp. so it contains only one file which is jar. does this create the problem?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Environment:

```
springBootVersion = '1.3.2.RELEASE'
JDK6 (yes it is)
Ubuntu 12.04
```

Comment: Your application has not been registered as service. So you can use service command to check the status of your application. For more information check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922554/java-running-as-a-unix-service

Comment: Thanks for reply.but i still dint get it right. do i need to write extra script for it ? which is not mentioned in spring doc link i cited . so where should i use 
$nohup java -jar program.jar & this?

Comment: Actually, the spring doc is not very explicit. You also need to do the steps for "systemctl" when using "service". The official documentation for Debian "service" command is clearer: **https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Services** Using spring documentation: **https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-install**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register your jar as service. Look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-initd-service

Comment: i already have followed the same link in my question and completed 55.1.1  section.but the problem still coming probably i am missing something

Comment: What is result when you execute service myapp start?

Comment: "Failed to start" , as I mentioned it in the question

Comment: Look at logs of your application and there will be reason

Comment: application is not started when i tried service myapp start. so i dont have application log

Comment: Could you check if you have logs in /var/log/myapp.log or in directory where you install this app. Check also if you have permissions to run app.

Comment: it says start-stop-daemon: unrecognized option '--no-close'

Comment: edit /etc/init.d/myapp and remove '--no-close' option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105548/discussion-between-sasi-kathimanda-and-marok).

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, you may need to run: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` for your new service to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu you need reload deamon with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: [Ctrl + C] and [Ctrl + V] is not a solution, it's just a [copy of the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835146/spring-boot-init-d-not-not-running-process-not-found/54633150#54633150)